# Software to parse an XML file while being generated

Tags: xml, parser

I want to parse an XML file that is constantly being added to; the file may contain invalid tags because of this.

I want a parser that can parse until an error, then wait for data and continue from the same point.

Comment: Hmmm, something like `tail`, but for XML. Interesting. Can you code? You might have to make your own. In the meantime, it would help us if you could say which operating system you use & whether you are seeking a free program, or have a a budget in mind.

Comment: @Mawg I am using linux debian. Anyhow resolved the problem using some kind of logic. Thank you...

Comment: Could you please explain the "logic", so that it might help other people wanting to do the same thing?